# lilypad Protosnap, avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not respond

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, wearables

I just bought a lilypad Protosnap like this, and when I plug in my lipoBattery eveything works. (lights, buzzer, button)

now I am trying to follow the Quickstart.

[protosnap and main board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKY8f.jpg)
[my FTDI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZw1P.jpg)
Board: lilypad Arduino, Processor: ATmega328, Porter: /dev/cu.usbserial-A9AXPZJY (that's the only porter available and another one is Bluetooth)

I tried the basic blink code from example while all the lights are just blinking and the buzzer is beeping just like before. and the there is avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding. I don't know what's the problem here?

**I also got this when I am trying to upload. while it also happens when I am using my arduino uno but my uno works very well everytime, so I assume it's not the problem.

"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

User configuration file is "/Users/cillian/.avrduderc"

User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping**

Comment: I also got: System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/anrn/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

Answer (score 1):

**I already fixed the problem. It turns out that the FTDI converter I got is wrong. I bought another one which is produced for lilypad (and more expensive) specifically and now everything works very well!!**

P.S I don't know why there are people downgrade my question if you are not helping. I just provide my solution here in case that some people meet the same problem.